# Vert.x check if request header contains X-Requested-With and deny if not contains

Tags: java, csrf, vert.x, csrf-protection

In vert.x I want to deny requests if "X-Requested-With" header not exists in header. I want to do this for CSRF protection? I couldn't find a good document abour this. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that in routes handling:

```
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route("/api/*").handler(event -> {
        if(event.request().getHeader("X-Requested-With") == null){
            event.response().setStatusCode(403).putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8").end("{\"message\":\"Not authorized\"}");
        }else{
            event.next();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have tried same configuration with router.route().handler(.... adding "/api/*" solved my problem. Thanks